# Display Most Recent Post Widget Title On Page

Tags: widgets, recent-posts, get-the-title

I want to display the Recent Posts Widget **title** on a page, however I could not find a solution yet.

I dont want to display the recent posts on the page **only the title** of the most recent posts widget, given by user.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Can't really understand what you want to display, you want to display a title that says recent posts? or you want to display the titles of recent posts (How many recent posts you want to display?)

Comment: @Buttered_Toast the user can give a title to every widget in the widget panel. I gave the title "Most Recent" to the recent post widget and its shown with the widget. I want to take that title "Most Recent" and display it on the page.

Comment: Exactly what you just added to your question, this is the way to change the name of the widget. If you don't see it in the page maybe the theme has some css that hides it, maybe there is a filter that hooks into it and removes it. I would start with checking the css. If its a not your theme, contact the theme author about this

Comment: @Buttered_Toast The widget is working fine displaying the title. I just want to display the title on a different page without the posts, just the title itself.